# Get random number from array, no repeat (with Timer)

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, timer, undefined

Hi and Thank you for reading this post.

I'm trying to create an automatic Bingo call-out-loud number game but I keep getting undefined on the console log. Any ideas?

I have an array, this items need to be call randomly with no repeat, and when finish stop and say something like "the end" or "finish".

Thank you so much!

```
var nums = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"],
ranNums = [],
i = nums.length,
j = 0;

setInterval(getNum,2000);

function getNum(){
  j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
  ranNums.push(nums[j]);
  nums.splice(j,1);
  console.log(ranNums[ranNums.length-1]);
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you consistently get `undefined` in the console log?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not modify the 'i' variable once you splice the array.

For example, your array can end up becoming

```
nums = ["one","two","three","four","ten"]
```

while your 'i' is still 10, so 'j' can get values which are too big for your array, thus leading you to undefined.

To solve this, make 'i' get the new array length or decrease it by 1 at the end of the function

Answer (score 1):

I hope that will help u :)

```js
var nums = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"],
ranNums = [],
j = 0;

intervall = setInterval(getNum,2000);
  function getNum(){
  
    i = nums.length
    
    if(i == 0) {
      clearInterval(intervall)
      console.log('the end')
    } else {
        console.log(i)
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i));
        ranNums.push(nums[j]);
        nums.splice(j,1);
        console.log(ranNums[ranNums.length-1]);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! They all work perfectly!!!  Very nice of you!  Don’t you love when javascript works like magic???  

Answer (score 1):

Firstly The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing. [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  Thats why you get undefined (Cause you modify the initial array length.
Also if you searched a little bit you could find [Getting a random integer between two values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Also you didn't mention when you want to stop. But bellow is Bingo!!!

```js
var nums = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"],
  ranNums = [],
  i = nums.length,
  j = 0;



setInterval(getNum2, 2000);

function getNum2() {
  var min = Math.ceil(null); //rounds a number up to the next largest whole number or integer
  var max = Math.floor(nums.length); // returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number
  var rdNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  // You can set a rult when you want to stop for e.g 
  // if (ranNums.length === 5){ clearInterval(getNum2)}
  ranNums.push(nums[rdNumber]);
  console.log(nums[rdNumber]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while operand for example:

```js
    var nums = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"];
    var usedNums = [];
    while (nums.length) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nums.length - 1));
      var randomNumber = nums.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
      console.log('number ' + randomNumber.toString());
      usedNums.push(randomNumber);
    };
    console.log('nums end');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems alright, just need updates of `nums` length with each element pops. Here is one way to do it.

```js
var nums = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"],
ranNums = [],
i = nums.length,
j = 0;

setInterval(getNum,2000);

function getNum(){
  i=nums.length
  if(i!=0){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i));
    ranNums.push(nums[j]);
    nums.splice(j,1);
    console.log(ranNums[ranNums.length-1]);
  }else{
    alert('The end');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes here. You are not resetting value of `i` here. Also `Math.random * i` instead of `i+1`

See below code for reference

```
var nums = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"],
ranNums = [],
i = nums.length,
j = 0;

setInterval(getNum,2000);

function getNum() {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i));
    // console.log(j);  
    ranNums.push(nums[j]);
    nums.splice(j,1);
    i = nums.length;
    let newValue = ranNums[ranNums.length-1];
    if (!newValue) {
        newValue = "The end!!"
    }
    console.log(newValue);
}
```